# ActivatedRoute não chama o service antes de atualizar a pagina angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Ola, usei o routerLink que passa um id para a url, que busco esse id e passo como parametro para a função que busca os dados da api, mas quando clico no meu link ele redireciona pra rota que eu quero, porem não mostra meus dados que estou iterando, e o array do retorno da api fica undefined. Mas se eu recarrego a rota novamente ai sim ele mostra os dados:

**Este é meu link**

```
<a routerLink="/wines/{{uvas.id_uva}}">{{uvas.uva}}</a></li>
```

**Meu component**

```
ngOnInit() {

this.Wine = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
  this._dataService.getWine(params.get('id'))

  );
}
```

**Meu Service**

```
getWine(id): Observable<IWine> {
return this.http.get<IWine>(`http://localhost:8888/exemplo/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: Vou comentar o problema que tive, todas as respostas que foram postadas aqui estavam certa e funcionando, o problema estava no carousel do angular2-materialize que estou usando, os dados estão sendo iterados neste carousel depois que ele ja estava carregado, e então não carregando os dados que veio do service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O valor so vai existir dentro do sbuscribe pois e la que o tem o retorno do http e equivalente ao promise.then.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.activatedRoute.params.map(params => params['id'])
.switchMap(id => id ? this.dataService.getWine(id) : Observable.empty())
.subscribe(wines=>   this.Wines = wines);

}
```

Se tiver mais duvidas pesquise por asyncornicidade. Mais especificamente o async pipe no angular

Comment: Poise, mudei ja usando async pipe e nada, o problema que eu chamo a rota e ele não mostra os dados, mas quando recarrego novamente dai ele mostra

Comment: editei minha resposta, basicamente vc estava pegando o snapshot invés de ver o observable de params.

Comment: tentei mas ainda nada, vou postar uma outra tentativa que fiz, funcionou ele busca certo cada informação que preciso conforme o id da rota que cliquei, mas ainda precisa recarregar a rota pra mostrar os dados.